# Change of variables in $\iiiint$ or $\idotsint$?

Tags: integration

I apologize if this is a question that has been asked before, but I have seen that it is possible to change variables in single, double and triple integrals. Now what about quadruple integrals, or $n$-integrals? I've Googled a lot and cannot seem to find anything on it.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Yes. It works in any number of dimensions. See Lang, "Real and Functional Analysis".

Comment: Yes. Look up the Jacobian matrix

Comment: @Dylan I see, so the same concepts work for  $n$-integrals as they do for double and triples.